# Set button in vertical center of table view cell.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have button and a label in my table view cell placing one after other vertically.

In my xib design i placed my button then below it placed my label.

if the string for label is  empty then i want to set the button as vertically center in table view cell and hide the label.

if have tried following code for my implementation but button does not come in vertical center position.

```
if([labelString isEqualToString:@""]){
    _label.hidden = YES;
    _button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
}
```

it would be helpful if get suggestion for fixing this problem.

Comment: Are you using autolayout or frame approach?

Comment: i am using auto layout.

Comment: @tahiat handle it with priority

Comment: or you can enable/disable some constraints

Comment: Thank you for your help. i have solve it using priority for constraints. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One approach: use dynamic setting of constraints.

In InterfaceBuilder:

1. Put your button and label inside an enclosing wrapper view.
2. Constrain the wrapper view to be centered in the main view.
3. Constrain the button and the label to be of fixed height, and the top of the label to be constrained to the bottom of the button (with spacing if desired).
4. Constrain the top of the wrapper to the top of the button.
5. Constrain the bottom of the wrapper with two separate constraints: one to the bottom of the button (but make this inactive), and one to the bottom of the label (active.).
6. Make both of those constraints outlets so that you can access them in code.
7. Leave the wrapper height otherwise unconstrained. Thus it will "shrink-wrap" to the combined height of the button and label.

In code:

When the label is empty, activate the constraint that pins the wrapper to the button instead of to the label:

```
    BOOL hideLabel = [labelString isEqualToString:@""];
    _label.hidden = hideLabel;
    _wrapperToButtonConstraint.active = hideLabel;
    _wrapperToLabelConstraint.active = !hideLabel;
```

Now the shrink-wrap effect will make the wrapper have the same height as the button, and since the wrapper is centered, so will the button be centered.